# Python: how to map values between a matrix and a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe `net` that contains the distance `d` between two locations `A` and `B`.

```
net =
        A  B   d
    0   5  3  3.5 
    1   2  0  2.3
    2   3  2  1.2 
    3   4  5  2.2   
    4   0  1  3.2
    5   0  3  4.5
```

Then I have a symmetric matrix `M` that contains all the possible distances between two pairs, so:

```
M =
    0    1    2    3    4    5
0   0   3.2  2.3  4.5  1.7  5.2 
1  3.2   0   2.1  0.7  3.9  3.8 
2  2.3  2.1   0   1.2  1.5  4.7 
3  4.5  0.7  1.2   0   3.2  3.5     
4  1.7  3.9  1.5  3.2   0   2.2
5  5.2  3.8  4.7  3.5  2.2   0
```

I want to generate a new dataframe `df1` that contains two random different locations `A` and `B` in the same distance interval `ds > np.floor(d) & ds < np.floor(d)+1`.

This is what I am doing

```
H = []
W = []
for i in net.index:
    tmp = net['d'][i]
    ds = np.where( (M >  np.floor(tmp)) & (M < np.floor(tmp)+1) )
    size = len(ds[0])
    ind = randint(size) ## find two random locations with distance ds
    h = ds[0][ind]
    w = ds[1][ind]
    H.append(h)
    W.append(w)
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['A'] = H
df1['B'] = W
```

Answer (score 1):

group `M` by floor division of 1.  Then use that to query and sample

```
g = M.stack().index.to_series().groupby(M.stack() // 1)
net.d.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(g.get_group(x // 1).sample(1).iloc[0], list('AB')))
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'vstack`